# Variables w/ Cell Address & Formulas

Tags: vba, excel

I have been to this website many times for help creating macros in Excel's VBA editor.  In fact, I used this website to help create a macro that updates our company's billing spreadsheet semi-automatically.  However, I would like to take to the human error factor out of the process and make it more foolproof.  I just cannot figure out how to search or phrase what I want to do to find the code sequence that will work.  Here is my current code that works perfectly, but leaves room for human error:

```
'   Copy of "New Totals" columns to "Previous Billing" columns of new "Current Billing" worksheet
Sheets("Current Billing").Select
Range("o4").Select
Set Rng1 = Application.InputBox("Select complete range of New Totals" & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & _
    "Please start at O4:Q4 and proceed to the end, but do not include the Totals at the bottom", _
    "New Totals Selection", Type:=8)
Rng1.Select
Rng1.Copy
Sheets("Current Billing (2)").Select
Range("h4").Select
Range("h4").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
    :=False, Transpose:=False
Application.CutCopyMode = False
Range("h4").Select
```

By asking the user to select the cells that need to be copied, I have left room for errors in case cells get missed in copying or the wrong cells are copied.  I would like to minimize that potential.  I came across this code that others have recommended as a better way to copy data:

```
Dim Rng1 As Range
Dim rng4 As Range

Sheets("Current Billing").Select
Sheets("Current Billing").Copy Before:=Sheets(2)
Sheets("Current Billing").Select

Set Rng1 = Sheets("Current Billing").Range("o:q")
'Range o:q is "New Totals" referenced above
Set rng4 = Sheets("Current Billing (2)").Range("h:j")
'Range h:j is "Previous Billing" referenced above

rng4.Value = Rng1.Value
```

But what that does is erase 3 formulas I have that "Sum" the data to give totals of the columns in range H:J.  I would like to find the "Total" row at the end of my data, and rebuild the formula in the proper cell.  As an example, I have a "Sum" formula in cells H47 and J47 with a range of H4:H45 and J4:J45 respectively.

With all of that explanation, how do I create a macro sequence that will automatically rebuild a formula in a specific cell that will have a variable row location, but static column location (usually)?  I apologize for the long winded explanation, but thank for all of your assistance.  And please let me know if I need to clarify anything.  Have a great day.

[Edit 3-14-18 @ 8:43PDT] My range O:Q contain formulas that do not need to be copied to my range H:J, all I need are the values copied over.  This is where my issue arises, because my =Sum() function varies in row location, I cannot figure out how to identify the specific cell the =Sum() occurred and reinsert it.  I did some research and found the following three functions

=index(H:H, Match(""total"", A:A, 0))

=CELL(""address"",index(H:H, Match(""total"", A:A, 0)))

=offset(CELL(""address"",index(H:H, Match(""total"", A:A, 0))),-1,0)

but I cannot figure out how to set my variables properly to then be able to reinsert the =Sum() function.  Thank you for the help.

[Edit 3/15/2018 @ 9:10 PDT]  Below is the modified code based upon the code GMalc created that works with 2 clarifications requested.  How to insert the actual =Sum() function into the last Total cell instead of the value; and how to prevent an extra line of data being added directly below the last Total row.

```
Dim ws1 As Worksheet
Dim ws2 As Worksheet
Set ws1 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Current Billing")
Set ws2 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Current Billing (2)")

Dim lRow As Long
Dim lRowa As Long
lRow = ws1.Cells(Rows.Count, 15).End(xlUp).Row
lRowa = ws2.Cells(Rows.Count, 15).End(xlUp).Row

   ws2.Range("H4:J" & lRowa).Value = ws1.Range("O4:Q" & lRow).Value
   'ws2.Range("H4").Value

Dim lRow2 As Long
Dim fRow As Long

lRow2 = ws2.Range("H4:J" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
fRow = lRow + 1

     ws2.Range("H" & fRow) = WorksheetFunction.Sum(Range("H4:H" & lRow2))
```

Comment: So I'm not sure if I understand, but you want to automatically select the range of cells that contain the `=SUM()` formula? Do you have an idea usually where these would be at, or can they be anywhere on the worksheet?

Comment: Hi Jason, in response to your second question, the Total row containing the =Sum() function can occur at any row in the spreadsheet depending upon the amount of data we are trying to track for the project's billing.  After I do a copy of the prior month's billing data, I would like to be able to find the 'Total' row and reinsert my =Sum() function back into place.  I will add further clarifications in my question with more information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Edit 1: You need to learn **how not to use Select**. This is what I think you are asking for. The code copies all the new data from "Current Billing" from O4 to the last row. Then it paste the data into "Current Billing (2)" at cell H4. It then adds the the Sum function in the cell below the last row to sum the data from H4 to the last row. You should be able to add the summing for rows I and J. I've tested this multiple time, you should have not problems.

```
Dim ws1 As Worksheet
Dim ws2 As Worksheet
'Ensure your worksheet names are correct
Set ws1 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Current Billing")
Set ws2 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Current Billing (2)")

'Set the last row in column 15, to copy the dynamic range.
Dim LastRow As Long
LastRow = ws1.Cells(Rows.Count, 15).End(xlUp).Row
    'Copy your range from "Current Billing" to "Current Billing (2)" starting at H4
    ws1.Range("O4:Q" & LastRow).Copy ws2.Range("H4")

'Set the last row variable for the "Current Billing (2)" worksheet because it will be different then the "Current Billing" worksheet
Dim LastRow2 As Long
'Set the variable for the empty cell below the last row in column H
Dim fRow As Long

LastRow2 = ws2.Cells(Rows.Count, "H").End(xlUp).Row
fRow = LastRow2 + 1

'Insert the sum formula in the empty cell below the last row in column H
ws2.Cells(fRow, "H").Formula = "=SUM(H4:H" & LastRow2 & ")"
```

Comment: Hello GMalc, thank you for the suggestion on the code.  I tried running it and found two issues, and potentially a third.  The first, is my Range O:Q contains formulas to show the sum of column H and column L.  When the copy occurred, the formulas were also copied and there is a #Value error in the cell, all I need copied are the values.  The second is a Run-time error '1004': Method 'Range' of object '_Global' failed at line 1Row2.  The third potential issue I am seeing is with the xlUp commands.  There may be gaps in the data that could cause that command to miss data.

Comment: [Continued comment from above] I will edit my original question to add more information.  Thanks for your help.

Comment: Good morning @GMalc.  Your code as stated above almost worked, I had to make a couple of modifications that I will post in an edit of my question so you can see the changes I made.  With those changes it works! Thank you!  I have 2 follow up questions, regarding the code.  Is there a way to actually insert the =Sum() function into the "Total" row instead of inserting the =Sum() value?  My second question is, the first cell of data in "H4" is being copied into the cell directly under my total cell. What could be causing this?  Again, thank you for all of the help!!  Have a great day.

Comment: Could you also please explain how/why the code works?  I understand enough to make modifications or mimic the code to make it work, but I don't fully understand the syntax of the functions to use them again in a different worksheet.  Thanks again for your help.  Have a great day.

Comment: @ Elliot, I've edited my answer with comments.  If you want to put the sum formula in the other two columns copy the line of code and change the column letter, like this... `ws2.Cells(fRow, "I").Formula = "=SUM(I4:I" & LastRow2 & ")"`

Comment: Thank you so much for all of your help and adding the comments to the code.  I will test everything out later today or tomorrow and see how it works.  On a side note, I took your suggestion of not to use the select function and have started reworking the rest of my code to make it more streamlined.  Thanks again, have a great day.

Comment: I tried doing an upvote, but it said because I have less than 15 reputation? the vote would be registered, but would not appear.  I have marked your answer as helpful.  I'm sorry, I'm new to posting on the site, so I'm not sure if I missed anything on giving you credit.  I am trying to make sure all the bases are covered.  Thanks and have a great day.

Comment: @Elliott, I'm glad i could help